# How to know which 802.11 standard is used by a router

Tags: linux, router, 802.11

Is there a command that can help me get the 802.11 standard used by a router.

PS : My OS is Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `sudo iw dev INTERFACE scan` to figure out the used protocol.
(requires kernel >=3.0)

If you don't have it then install it with `sudo apt-get install iw`

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62271) over on Stack Exchange Unix explains how to determine what standard is being used.

Comment: You'll have to pick out the correct SSID from all nearby WiFi access points, or go `iw dev INTERFACE scan ssid SSID`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a command that can help me get the 802.11 standard used by a router.

It depends:

- The normal way would be to log into the accesspoint and check the capabilities on the device itself.
- Failing that you could check with which standard you are connected o the WAP (assing you have wireless in your system). See Jesse's answer.
- With no connection but with a wireless NIC installed you might be able to eavesdrop in what is send though the air. Essentially snif on the communication of what is actually used.
- And lastly, you could alway read the documentation for the WAP.